# Symfony find field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Developers entity and table named CodeUserReference

```
class CodeUserReference
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artel\CustomerBundle\Entity\Developers", inversedBy="newreference")
 */
protected $alluser;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $codereference;
```

and Developers

```
class Developers extends SUser
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255,  unique=false, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
protected $email;
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Artel\CustomerBundle\Entity\CodeUserReference", inversedBy="alluser")
 */
protected $newreference;
```

I have get query in my Action

```
public function profileGetAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $code_user_reference = $em->getRepository('ArtelCustomerBundle:CodeUserReference')->findOneByCodereference($request->query->get('reference'));
    $user_by_email = $em->getRepository('ArtelCustomerBundle:Developers')->findOneByEmail($request->query->get('email'));
    if (!empty($code_user_reference) && empty($user_by_email))
    {
        $id = $code_user_reference->getAlluser()->getId();
        $user_by_reference = $em->getRepository('ArtelCustomerBundle:Developers')->findOneById($id);

        $user_by_reference_json = $em->getRepository('ArtelCustomerBundle:Developers')->createQueryBuilder('d')
            ->where('d.id= :id')
            ->groupBy('d.id')
            ->setParameter('id', $code_user_reference->getAlluser()->getId())
            ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

        echo json_encode( array('user' => $user_by_reference_json));
        die;
    }
    If(empty($code_user_reference) && !empty($user_by_email))
     .......
```

I get Id in code_user_reference, then I find Developers objects with this ID, then I create a QueryBuilder and in this QueryBuilder I find the developers objects again, for JSON table. I find this very hard, who knows easier practics ?

Answer (score 0):

There is certanly mismapping.

if you have @ORM\ManyToOne from one site, there should be @ORM\OneToMany from other.

Or, if you need many-to-many relationship, there should be @ORM\ManyToMany on both entities.

Also, relation should be mapped at one side. If you have `(targetEntity="Artel\CustomerBundle\Entity\Developers", inversedBy="newreference")` it means it should be mapped here

something like

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artel\CustomerBundle\Entity\Developers", inversedBy="newreference")
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_developer", referencedColumnName="id")
```

and at the other side must be `mappedBy` instead of `inversedBy`

```
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Artel\CustomerBundle\Entity\CodeUserReference", mappedBy="alluser")
```

Comment: And how find user by Codereference
`$code_user_reference = $em-getRepository('ArtelCustomerBundle:CodeUserReference')-findOneByCodereference($request->query->get('reference'));
$id = $code_user_reference->getAlluser()->getId();
        $user_by_reference = $em-getRepository('ArtelCustomerBundle:Developers')->findOneById($id);`
because this example not gight Ithink